# Optical zoom for ios using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

Hi I am developing an app which has a bar scanning option so I am using zbar but I am making my own camera view port and sending the image to zbar scanner but I need to zoom the camera programmatically and I need optical zooming. I am able to do digital zoom but I need optical zooming option. Any help?
For making the camera view port I am using `AVCaptureSession`. And here is my code

```
-(void)initializecam{ 
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
//session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];


[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];
_stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
[session startRunning];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use optical zoom, because there is no such thing currently in iOS devices. Just looked newest iPhone 5s and it has digital zoom only. So you need external device to use optical zoom.

Comment: Can you please provide a link stating that, for iPhone 5